# Windows timer sometimes runs twice as fast

Tags: c++, windows, timer

I'm using a timer in my game, it is started inside a singleton and has a callback called each millisecond. However, sometimes it runs twice as fast. It is really rare, I have only seen it 2 or 3 times (10.000+ builds, thousands of executions).

This is the (important part of the) code:

```
//local variable in the .cpp:
static float milliseconds=0;

//the "actual" variable used in the game
long int MilliSecondTimer::milliseconds=0;

void CALLBACK TimerProc(UINT wTimerID, UINT msg, DWORD dwUser, DWORD dw1, DWORD dw2)
{
    milliseconds++;
    MilliSecondTimer::GetInstance()->SetTime(int(milliseconds), int(guimseconds));
}

MilliSecondTimer::MilliSecondTimer()
{
    UINT TimerID = timeSetEvent(1, 0, TimerProc, 0, TIME_PERIODIC | TIME_CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
}
```

Is it so that if the creation of the singleton takes more than 1 msec, then it will be called twice because the timer function will call

```
MilliSecondTimer::GetInstance()->SetTime(...)
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: [Why are the Multimedia Timer APIs (timeSetEvent) not as accurate as I would expect?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mediasdkstuff/2009/07/02/why-are-the-multimedia-timer-apis-timesetevent-not-as-accurate-as-i-would-expect/)

Comment: You do not get 1 msec unless you *also* call timeBeginPeriod().  Or another program does it for you, like Chrome.

Comment: This code comes from a time when the windows timer only had a granularity around 50-60 msec. This isn't the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be hard to reproduce as you said it only occured rarely. But i belive your initiall thought for the cause of the problem might be true. In the MSDN documentation of timeSetEvent it says:

> The multimedia timer runs in its own thread

That means, as you said, if the singleton is taking more than 1ms to create, then the constructor of the singleton will be called twice in this case. The second call to the constructor may result from the `MilliSecondTimer::GetInstance()->SetTime(...)` call in the first timer callback function since at this point the singleton is not yet created and `MilliSecondTimer::GetInstance()` will call the constructor again which in turn create another timer object. Since each timer runs in its own thread, you will have now two timers working on(increment) the same data(static float milliseconds) which explains why it runs twice as fast. And if this is the case, then since two instances of the singleton are created in the process but the singleton instance pointer is eventually pointing to one of them, there might also be a memory leak as a result.

Comment: The multimedia timer doesn't "run in a thread". It runs in a time critical one, and that one comes from the timer Interrupt. When returning, the thread goes away. Also, I don't think there could be a memory leak.

Comment: @Valmond I think what the documentation is trying to say is the callback function pointed by lpTimeProc that is called upon expiration of periodic events will be called(i.e run) in a different thread than the one that starts a specified timer event(in this case the singleton constructor MilliSecondTimer::MilliSecondTimer()). That is why i thought you will have two callback function in two threads increamenting your static float milliseconds variable making it look it runs twice as fast.

Comment: @Valmond regarding the memory leak if we assume the problem is that the construction of the singleton object is taking more than 1ms then your first callback function will result in another call to the constructor of the singleton class by **MilliSecondTimer::GetInstance()** function which i assume will try to create the singleton object dynamically and assign the result to the instance pointer data member of that class. In this case you have one pointer but dynamically created two objects of the singleton class. Anyway this assumes that the singleton class takes more than 1ms to construct.

Comment: Fair enough :-) I have changed the code (construction first, and only then a call to a function that starts the timer) so hopefully this won't happen again (or I'll be back ;-)